# Grid View position in Intent is not increasing

Tags: java, android

I'm setting up grid view gallery and in Intent id, I need to increase the int position for showing the next photo in the gallery but is not increasing this is the code:

public class FullScreenActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
private ImageView imageView;
private ImageButton BtnNext, BtnBefore, BtnShare, BtnDownload;
private int position;
private ImageAdapter imageAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_full_screen);

    imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_view_screen);
    BtnNext = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imgBtnNext);
    BtnBefore = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imgBtnBefore);
    BtnShare = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imgBtnShare);
    BtnDownload = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imgBtnDownload);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    position = intent.getExtras().getInt("id");
    imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(this);
    imageView.setImageResource(imageAdapter.ImagesArray[position]);


    BtnNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            imageView.setImageResource(imageAdapter.ImagesArray[position + 1]);
            Toast.makeText(FullScreenActivity.this, "position: " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    BtnBefore.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }
    });

    BtnShare.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }
    });

    BtnDownload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }
    });
}
```

}

Comment: you have declared position as final, it will not change its value.

Comment: I removed the final and value still not increase

Comment: can you please add the whole code so that I can help you.

Comment: ok I Will add the whole code

Comment: check my answer, hope it helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not tracking the position value just writing the code position + 1, your actual code should be like this :

```
BtnNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            position = position + 1;
            imageView.setImageResource(imageAdapter.ImagesArray[position]);
            Toast.makeText(FullScreenActivity.this, "position: " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }); //note you should also write the code to check if the position exceeds the final value
```

Comment: no problem, do let me know if you need any more help in this logic.